# How to dynamically add css after image upload on node?

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

I have used `drupal_add_js()` for my profile content type and modified CSS using jquery `.css()` function. in this content type i have image upload field but when i upload image the image preview display is changed. my question is how can i apply the style for image preview field which is added after image upload.

Answer (score 1):

If you use drupal behaviors to modify the css, it should run after the ajax too.

eg.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.example', context).css('backgroud-color', '#ff0000');
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

More info at: http://drupal.org/node/756722